# Django Http404 returns status=200

Tags: django

When my application raises `Http404` the status-code returned is 200, which I find odd.

It returns and renders my 404-template, so it should work, but the status-code is wrong.

Please find the views and urls-file below:

```py
#views.py

from django.http import Http404
def test_404_view(request):
   raise Http404

def error_404(request, exception):
    return render(request,"MyApp/404.html")
```

```py
#urls.py

handler404 = 'myapp.views.error_404'
.
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the [**`status=…`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) code in your `render` call, this is by default a 200:

```
def error_404(request, exception):
    return render(request,'MyApp/404.html', status=404)
```